# Best practice of executing dynamic SQL strings via prepared statements and procedures

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

**Background:** I am building a Springboot+mySQL app that uses Spring Data JPA native queries (i.e. `@Query(value = "...", nativeQuery = true)` to retrieve database data.

We have to use the same SQL in every query we write to enable certain functionality (this can be seen in the example below). And wanted a way to remove this duplicate SQL and instead only declare it once. An option presented was to pass a dynamic SQL string into a stored procedure and then build a prepared statement by concatenating this dynamic SQL string with our static shared SQL string (show in example below).

**Question:**
This doesn't seem like a good idea to me, but I am not knowledgeable enough about databases to given the exact technical reasons. Is the below example safe, reasonable, and best-practice? Are there ways to mitigate issues with this approach, or are there other approaches to use instead?

**Basic setup code:**

```
-- create tables
CREATE TABLE docs (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  rev INTEGER NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE more_docs (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  more_content VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE docs_metadata (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  letter VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE metadata_nums (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  metadata_id INTEGER,
  num INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO docs VALUES (1, 1, 'abc');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES (2, 1, 'def');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES (3, 2, 'ghi');
INSERT INTO docs VALUES (4, 1, 'jkl');

INSERT INTO more_docs VALUES (1, 'aaa');
INSERT INTO more_docs VALUES (2, 'bbb');
INSERT INTO more_docs VALUES (3, 'ccc');
INSERT INTO more_docs VALUES (4, 'ddd');

INSERT INTO docs_metadata VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO docs_metadata VALUES (2, 'b');
INSERT INTO docs_metadata VALUES (3, 'c');
INSERT INTO docs_metadata VALUES (4, 'd');

INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (1, 1, 5);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (2, 1, 6);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (3, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (4, 2, 6);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (5, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (6, 3, 6);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (7, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO metadata_nums VALUES (8, 4, 6);
```

**Approach in question:**

```
-- create stored procedure
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FILTER_EVAL (IN dynamic_statement TEXT, IN num INT, IN letter VARCHAR(1))
BEGIN 
  SET @dynamic_statement := CONCAT("SELECT X.* FROM  (", dynamic_statement, ")  X INNER JOIN (SELECT DM.*, MN.num FROM docs_metadata DM INNER JOIN metadata_nums MN ON DM.id = MN.metadata_id) M ON X.id = M.id WHERE M.num = ", num, " AND M.letter = '", letter, "'");
  PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
  EXECUTE prepared_statement;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
END//
DELIMITER ;

-- fetch some values
CALL FILTER_EVAL("SELECT * FROM docs WHERE rev = 1", 5, 'b')
```

Comment: There is very little that you achieve by doing this. You might as well create the full SQL statement and pass it to `@Query`.

Comment: @slaakso It is my understanding that `@Query` can only accept constant expressions, so the whole SQL statement would have to be pre-defined as a constant value before being passed in, defeating the purpose of this dynamic approach.

Comment: What you are describing was described — as a cautionary tale, not as an example of a good practice — on TheDailyWTF in 2009: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/For-the-Ease-of-Maintenance If I were code-reviewing this, it would get a hard veto vote from me. Start over.